# Android NV12ToARGB LibYUV?

Tags: android, argb, libyuv

I want to convert `byte[]` NV12 format to ARGB.
In LibYUV, I found that:

```
 LIBYUV_API
int NV12ToARGB(const uint8* src_y, int src_stride_y,
               const uint8* src_uv, int src_stride_uv,
               uint8* dst_argb, int dst_stride_argb,
               int width, int height);
```

How can I get these params from NV12 data? Anyone can help me? Thanks!